# Double click action in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to use a double click action in SSRS. I have a text box I wish for the user to double click an object to drill to another url. Right now we are using to following:

[image: ssrs action arrow]

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://x2/jobs/" & Fields!job_id.Value & "/operations/" & Fields!mold_equip_id.Value & "','_blank'))"
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?  You have already implemented the `action` functionality on the text box to open another report...?

Comment: Right, but the action is only for a single click. My boss wants it on a double click.

Comment: Hahaha I see.  No, that is not impossible.  It is also not how links work anywhere...